# notification with shared preference in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm beginner in android programming, im trying to build a small application to get notifications from the user then trigger this notification. After that the user can see this notification and show it when the button is pressed. But the app closed unexpectedly when i run it.

When i remove these lines from the code:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putString("show",nname.getText().toString());
edit.commit();
```

it works, but shows an empty notification.
I didn't know where the the     problem is - can anyone help me please?

```
   public void triggerNotification(View v) {

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("show",nname.getText().toString());
    edit.commit();
    //Instantiate notification with icon and ticker message 
    Notification notifyObj=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                                            "Notification message!",
                                            System.currentTimeMillis());


    //PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects it 
    PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                new Intent(this, NotifyActivity.class),
                                                  0);
    //Set the info that show in the notification panel    
    notifyObj.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification Created",
                                "Click here to see the message", i);



    //Value indicates the current number of events represented by the notification
    notifyObj.number=++count;
    //Set default vibration
    notifyObj.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    //Set default notification sound
    notifyObj.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    //Clear the status notification when the user selects it
    notifyObj.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;    
    //Send notification
    notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notifyObj);
      }
```

**notify activity:**

```
public class NotifyActivity extends Activity {
private Button shButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notify);
    shButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sh);
    shButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
            String x= pref.getString("show", null);
            edit.commit();
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),  x ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}
```

this is logcat:

```
08-29 08:43:25.564: D/gralloc_goldfish(2166): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-29 08:43:32.075: D/AndroidRuntime(2166): Shutting down VM
08-29 08:43:32.075: W/dalvikvm(2166): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     ... 11 more
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     at com.prgguru.android.MainActivity.triggerNotification(MainActivity.java:46)
08-29 08:43:32.195: E/AndroidRuntime(2166):     ... 14 more
08-29 08:43:32.235: D/dalvikvm(2166): GC_CONCURRENT freed 97K, 8% free 2732K/2952K, paused 73ms+112ms, total 278ms
```

Comment: which lines are problemtic?

Comment: the first 4 lines in triggerNotification method

Comment: can you please add your logcat output ?

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

edit.putString("show",nname.getText().toString());
```

Check if "nname" is null.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make `pref` global variable?  Then try the code below:

```
pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Also I think the problem may result from here: `nname.getText().toString()`

Try any other string insted of it.